# Alternating prime series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, divergent-series

I was curious to know what the following limit is:

$$\lim_{x\downarrow-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_nx^{n-1}=\lim_{x\downarrow-1}(2+3x+5x^2+7x^3+11x^4+\dots)$$

where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime.

I graphed the first 6 or so partial sums:

[image]

but they converge terribly slow. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(x%5En*Prime%5Bn%5D,1,%E2%88%9E)) doesn't seem to have much of a clue either, and with some numerical testing, it seems this limit might go to $\infty$, which is quite strange, since it suggests even and odd indexed primes are not asymptotically equally spaced.

By using some asymptotes on the growth rate of the $n$th prime, one can also easily deduce that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_nx^{n-1}$$

converges absolutely for $|x|<1$.

Can we prove this limit goes off to $\infty$ or that it exists? And if it does exist, what is it's value?

Comment: Here are some computations I've done: taking $x=-1+1/N$ and summing the first $100N$ terms, we get an answer which should be within $10^{-5}$ to the true value, though I didn't do exact estimate):
`(100, -10.7514398861550)
(200, -4.67297770489999)
(300, 3.17796306897545)
(400, 11.4231942142518)
(500, 19.0902610888024)
(600, 25.7488008264050)
(700, 31.3173570621900)
(800, 35.8491110689575)
(900, 39.4318049018235)
(1000, 42.1548067007355)
(1100, 44.1023144294097)`
Though slowly, it does seem to tend without bound.

Comment: It is quite unlikely that the limit is "something".

Comment: (You did not use "asymptotes on the primes" but "asymptotics on (the growth of) primes". Primes do not have asymptotes)

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164936/is-the-alternating-sum-of-primes-2-3-5-p-n-asymptotic-to-n-ln-n-2 for something related.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since $p_n=\Theta(n\log n)$ by the weak version of the PNT, we may compute the wanted limit through a convolution with an approximate identity:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} \sum_{n\geq 1}p_n(x-1)^{n-1} = \lim_{n\to +\infty} \sum_{n\geq 1}p_n \int_{0}^{+\infty}n(x-1)^{n-1} e^{-nx}\,dx $$
where
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}n(x-1)^{n-1}e^{-nx}\,dx = \frac{n!}{e^n n^n}\approx\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{e^{2n}}$$
gives no issues, but
$$ \int_{0}^{1}n(x-1)^{n-1} e^{-nx}\,dx=(-1)^{n-1}\int_{0}^{n}\left(1-\frac{x}
{n}\right)^{n-1}e^{-x}\,dx $$
behaves like $\frac{(-1)^n}{2}$ for large values of $n$. In particular the existence of the wanted limit depends on the Cesàro summability of the sequence $\{(-1)^n p_n\}_{n\geq 1}$, hence on the distribution of prime gaps.

The result of Ping Ngai Chung and Shiyu Li [mentioned on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/164943/30521) implies that the wanted limit does not exist.

Comment: Ah, well that's quite nice. Thanks for your never ending insights!

Comment: Is it true that the _radius of convergence_ for $\sum p_{n+1} x^n$ is equal to one? It should be possible to plot the graph of this as a function of $x$ for $-1<x<1$.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, this follows from $p_n\sim n\log n$. Plotting the function accurately isn't that easy though