# Does there exist a database for aDirichlet L-series?

Tags: dirichlet-series

I want to find an L-function with a Dirichlet character $\chi$(or with a product of zeta function) to be equal the following series

$$ G(s)=\sum_{n  >1 }\frac{1}{n^s}=1+\frac{1}{4^s}+\frac{1}{6^s}+\frac{1}{8^s}+......$$ Where $n $ is not prime

I find Dirichlet L-series for $n$ are prime but I search for series with $n $ are  not prime
$$ L(s,\chi_{-4})=1+\frac{1}{2^s}-\frac{1}{3^s}+\frac{1}{5^s}-......$$

.

My question: does there exist some database for the coefficient of  Dirichlet L-series.

Comment: @DietrichBrude$n$ of the. First series $G(s)$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternating prime zeta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581045/alternating-prime-zeta-function)

Comment: See also [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181926/conjectured-relation-between-alternating-prime-zeta-series-and-riemann-zeta).

Comment: @Dietrich Brude I serac for series like $G(s)$ has integer not prime.

Comment: @reuns do you have idea